# Setting up Game Center with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, game-center

I'm having trouble with setting up a Game Center Leaderboard as I'm getting the error, `Cannot assign a value of type 'ViewController' to a value of type 'GKGameCenterControllerDelegate!'`. I believe it has something to do with the code I put at the top:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, GKGameCenterControllerDelegate, ADBannerViewDelegate {
//stuff
}
```

and the code I've put in one of my action buttons:

```
//shows leaderboard screen
            func showLeader() {
                var vc = self.view?.window?.rootViewController
                var gc = GKGameCenterViewController()
                gc.gameCenterDelegate = self            //<------This is the problem child.
                vc?.presentViewController(gc, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
```

What is going on? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting this error because your `ViewController` does not conform to protocol `GKGameCenterControllerDelegate`.

To solve this problem add this delegate method of `GKGameCenterControllerDelegate` into your `ViewController` class:

```
func gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish(gameCenterViewController: GKGameCenterViewController!){
    gameCenterViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

And your error will solve.